# How to Remove Half Received JSON String from an Array node js

Tags: json, node.js, tcp, tcpserver

I an using JSON and NODEJS

i am receiving data from TCP and i was receiving the data like this

```
[{"identification": {"id":3100,"version":1}},{"json1" : "THIS IS ONE json" },{"c]
```

or

```
[{"identification": {"id":3100,"version":1}},{"json1" : "THIS IS ONE json" },{"some n letters]
```

like this it is truncating while receiving TCP data i want to remove that half received data or is there any way to receive the full buffer

I want the Output to be

```
[{"identification": {"id":3100,"version":1}},{"json1" : "THIS IS ONE json" }]
```

Comment: Im not familliar with node js but as its javascript can you use plain javascript code in node js?? -- if so you could split the string after the 2nd coma -- see demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/zZKgd/

Comment: Its just a sample I receive that half json data after particular no of json objects. I am receiving it at after n  time like after 4 json objects of after 5  @Tasos

Comment: do you want to cut so its like this ("THIS IS ONE json" )

Comment: If I saperated at ',' then there also some ',' in the json data @Tasos

Comment: yes i saw that -- Update your Question with the expected result because (i want to remove that half received data) doenst explain much

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Can you show your code? My guess is that you expect the `data` event handler of a socket to deliver neatly segmented pieces of data, but it doesn't.

Comment: You can remove  the part of the json from the last occurrence of (,{)  ---https://jsfiddle.net/uro2d1sq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clumsy, but simple way would be to take the string/buffer and try to parse using `JSON.parse()`. Wrap it in a `try/catch` and only set the final value when it succeeds.

```js
var badJson = '[{"identification": {"id":3100,"version":1}},{"json1" : "THIS IS ONE json" },{"c]';

try {
    var result = JSON.parse(badJson);
}
catch(e) {
    console.log('bad json, not parsing yet');
}
```